# how to fix display picture bottom right corner of a div box

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am trying to fix a picture on the bottom right corner inside a div box...so that text can rollover it

I applied the css below to achieve this but it's not achieving the result.

```
.content_body
{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
padding-top: 30px;
background: #E6E6E0;
color: #555;
font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
min-height: 800px;
background-image: url(http://types4u.org/Tomike/temp/images/saturation.png) ;
background-position: right bottom; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


#footer
{
background: url(http://types4u.org/Tomike/temp/images/bg2.jpg) #E6E6E0;
color: white;
font-family: Lato, Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 1.5em;
padding: 40px 50px 50px 50px;
clear: both;
border-top: solid #000033 5px;
}

.design_by
{
float:     right;
font-size: 2.4em;
font-family: 'tangerine', cursive;

color:     white;
}

.copyright
{
float:     left;
font-size: 2.4em;
font-family: 'tangerine', cursive;
color:     white;
}


 <div class="content_body"> 
 hello
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
 <div class="copyright">
     <a href="#">mine.com</a> &copy copyright 2013 all rights reserved.
 </div>  

 <div class="design_by">  
     Design by <a href="http://types4u.org" target="http://types4u.org">types 4 u</a> 
 </div> 
 </div>
```

An example is here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CjXxk/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this update again: http://jsfiddle.net/CjXxk/1/

Everything is fine with your code but I think you forgot to add `background-repeat` to your css code:

```
.content_body
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 30px;
    background: #E6E6E0;
    color: #555;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    min-height: 800px;
    background-image: url(http://types4u.org/Tomike/temp/images/saturation.png) ;
    background-position: right bottom; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

What `background-repeat` does?
See [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp) about `background-repeat` on w3schools:

> The background-repeat property sets if/how a background image will be
>   repeated.
>
> By default, a background-image is repeated both vertically and
>   horizontally.

**Edit:**

Use `background-attachment: fixed;` to fix the background image. Also you can handle the footer overlap problem with `z-index`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the suggestion you gave worked. But I have another issue.. How can I fix the image so that text can rollover. Please see update.

Comment: @user1843335 What you need actually? Please explain more.

Comment: I want the bottom right image not to move when I scroll up/down

Answer (score 1):

You need to add:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Add this to make it static on scroll:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Comment: The suggestion you gave worked. But I have another issue.. How can I fix the image so that text can rollover. Please see update.

Comment: Thank you flem. One more thing sir.. I have a footer overlaps the static image. What I want to do is, I dont want the footer to overlap the image. pleasee see update

Comment: @user1843335. You will need to raise that as a new question as it is somewhat different from what you originally asked.